# Python - Not getting any output

Tags: python

```
class likedListNode:

    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

def rotateRight(head, k):

    if not head:
        return None
    if not head.next:
        return head

        # close the linked list into the ring

    old_tail = head
    n = 1
    while old_tail.next:
       old_tail = old_tail.next
       n += 1
    old_tail.next = head

        # find new tail : (n - k % n - 1)th node
        # and new head : (n - k % n)th node
    new_tail = head
    for i in range(n - k % n - 1):
        new_tail = new_tail.next
    new_head = new_tail.next

        # break the ring
    new_tail.next = None

    return new_head

node1=likedListNode("1")
node2=likedListNode("2")
node3=likedListNode("3")
node4=likedListNode("4")
node5=likedListNode("5")

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = node4
node4.next = node5

k=2
print (rotateRight(node1,k))
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you're trying to solve and what output you expect to see

Comment: what you want to print? A number? use `return new_head.value` in `rotateRight()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return `value` instead of `class`

```
class likedListNode:

    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next

def rotateRight(head, k):

    if not head:
        return None
    if not head.next:
        return head

        # close the linked list into the ring

    old_tail = head
    n = 1
    while old_tail.next:
       old_tail = old_tail.next
       n += 1
    old_tail.next = head

        # find new tail : (n - k % n - 1)th node
        # and new head : (n - k % n)th node
    new_tail = head
    for i in range(n - k % n - 1):
        new_tail = new_tail.next
    new_head = new_tail.next

        # break the ring
    new_tail.next = None


    return new_head.value

node1=likedListNode("1")
node2=likedListNode("2")
node3=likedListNode("3")
node4=likedListNode("4")
node5=likedListNode("5")

node1.next = node2
node2.next = node3
node3.next = node4
node4.next = node5

k=2
print (rotateRight(node1,k))
```